# Why do instructions on creation of roller chain sprocket tooth profile require redundant measurements?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bicycles, transmission, chain

I'm CADing a tooth profile for a bicycle chainring model and I'm referring my measurements and formulas to these sources:

- http://www.gearseds.com/files/design_draw_sprocket_5.pdf
- https://data.epo.org/publication-server/image?imageName=imgf0003&docId=2977669

One of them is the main instructional document while the other just presents a drawing of the profile with the same variables and equations as the first one. (though they do use different units)

They ask me to calculate some variables which will provide a graphical Point A and they make me calculate for the Angle B between a Line C and the x-axis with Point A as vertex, and it always ends up that Line C just connects the center of the roller circle and Point A. They also instructed me calculate for a length of Line D which is the same length of Line C from the circle's edge to Point A.

Why can't they just tell me to do that instead? I'm just wasting my time calculating for these practically redundant variables. It's not like they're teaching this for manual sketching, as they specifically use terms that are present in 2D drawing/CAD programs.

Comment: I think the document answers the question itself: "NOTE: This is primarily an algebra and geometry exercise..." If you can prove that your short cut always works, then use it! There is a comment in the document about points which seem to be coincident, but sometimes are not.

Comment: And the second one looks hand drawn and does not claim its a drawing instruction